# Limited Synchronization base on client information with Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I'm thinking of putting together this scenario for couchbase and I'm not quite sure whether it's possible?  I can't seem to find any reference to it.  So here it is.

[image: Proposed Architecture]

We have Bucket A as the main bucket.  It contains consolidated information for Client A, Client B and Client C.  Currently as it is, every one of them are connected directly to Couchbase main cluster.

What I'm thinking is if I could have Client A to have just their information in their own couchbase server but still synchronized with Bucket A in the main cluster, client B have their own couchbase server with their own information only and so is client C.  Will this scenario be possible?  and if it does, can someone help me with advise on how to accomplish it?

I read it somewhere that couchbase gateway, can pseudo does this except with one potential problem.  It can't synchronize with the existing bucket that's already existed in Couchbase Main cluster.  So what that means, is that Client A will have to create "Client Bucket A" and sync with Couchbase Main Cluster with bucket called "Client Bucket A".  If that truely is the case, that scenario just doesn't work for us.  Please advise?  Many thanks everyone...

P.S.:  I'm not quite sure whether this type of question falls under stackoverflow or ServerFault so pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client A,B and C are separate couchbase clusters? You can't selectively replicate parts of a bucket, you'd need to have 3 separate buckets, one for each client that then replicates to the external client clusters.

Comment: Thanks @avengedsixfold.  I think you may have misunderstood the question. Client A, B and C are part of the couchbase clusters but I don't want to replicate Client B's data to Client A's cluster.  Thus I'm thinking of installing a separate machine for each of the client for them to use and connect to main cluster if their machine with couchbase is down.  Is that clear and will it possible?

Comment: If client A should only receive data relating to client A then the main cluster needs to have 3 separate buckets.  Why do you need extra machines for the clients? Clients are separate users?  The main couchbase cluster can handle if a node goes down, you could always increase the number of replicas in the main cluster for more resiliency

Comment: Thanks @avengedsixfold.  The reason why the main cluster can only have 1 bucket is because there's a time when the client A will need to access Client B data and vice versa.

Comment: Also from memory utilization, if I have 4 gb worth of ram, I can have that memory shared by those 3 companies where if I created a bucket for every each of them, i'll need to have more physical memory since all memory once assigned, can't be shared by the buckets.  Thought?

Comment: Why do you need external clients that only have some data but then sometimes they need to access the other data?  What is stopping you having 3 buckets on the main cluster, each of the clients can connect to the different buckets by constructing different couchbase clients.

If you have 4gb of ram assign each bucket 1gb of ram.  There is some overhead to having multiple buckets (couchbase recommends to have as few buckets as possible <10).

Comment: Thanks @avengedsixfold.  The bucket limitation is also another challenge with having multiple buckets since we'll be having over 100 clients utilizing this system, multiple buckets scenario is just not doable.  However I think you may have already answered my question which is, it's not possible to selectively replicate data to other couchbase.  We can only selectively replicate certain bucket in the same cluster.  Which is too bad.  Many thanks again and I'll consider this as answered.